# what is a good practice for separating software module's UI files, put files in different folder or put files in different web solution in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, project-management, projects-and-solutions

**# Scenario large Enterprise project.**

If puts files in different folder, then solutions becomes very slow while build/debugging, also searching file in folder directory is painful sometimes.

If puts files in different web project then it is heard to manage .config, theme/master-page, App_code, image-folder etc.

I would greatly appreciate your suggestion & guideline.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to make your dev life more difficult if you don't see reasons to do this. :)
You should not separate UI in your folders if you will not need to reuse some components in separate project. so definitely don't separate your application by projects if you don't see reasons for that. 
This is strange that when you've added files in different folder and solution becomes slower to build / debug. What type of project you use? WebSite or WebApplication? 
I always separated in folder tree my ASP.NET pages / controls by very similar to site structure scheme. So if I have tree pages for users, like UserView / UserEdit and UserList - I do the folder Users and place here these tree views and maybe some UserControls which are related to these views.